# Phonegap html page will not open html page

Tags: phonegap

```
    Using iphone 5se. IOS 10. Phonegap v0.4.5
```

I have tried a number of methods to open a link to another page from my index.html. Will not work.  Same for a standard input Submit button.  Will only work if the Target is changed to _System.  Then that causes the safari browser to open my target page in the Safari browser.  Effectively navigating away from my phonegap window.  Have tried various access rights. 
 for example.  Not able to get any pages to open in the phonegap app window on.

```
<script>
function loginCheck()
{
alert("Login");
window.open("http://192.168.1.111:3000/user_login.html","_self");
}
</script>

 <input type="submit" class="submitbtn" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" onclick="loginCheck()">
```